# Why max-height and max-width properties can work

Tags: asp.net, image

I add `max-height`and `max-width` properties to the code, like this.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" max-height="124px" max-width="2083px" ImageUrl="~/1.jpg" Width="100%" />
```

It works fine. But when I look for Microsoft Docs, there is no `max-height`and `max-width` properties in `WebControl` class.

I also finded there are some solutions on Internet likes using function to resize image.

So I am curious why the code I modified can work and what is the best way.

Comment: This does not work with Firefox, Edge or Chrome. But anyway you normally would use CSS with Classes. `<asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="MyImage"`

Comment: With some controls you can use `style="...etc..."`, even though it's not official, and it will render fine. Not sure why that can work sometimes. JS functions are more advanced. If you know the sizes, CSS classes are best. I think you only need width, and height will self-adjust.

Comment: It works with latest Chrome in my machine, don't know why.

Comment: But it's doesn't matter. Now I use CssClass, thanks.